# Помощь в дописании регулярного выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Задачка с Codewars. Написать регулярное выражение, которое проверяет пароль, чтобы убедиться, что он соответствует следующим критериям:

1. Его длина минимум 6 символов
2. Содержит строчную и заглавную букву
3. Содержит цифру

Допустимые символы - буквенно-цифровые (Не `\`, `$` и т.д.)

Мой код:

`regex=r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$"`

Проблема моего кода:

По условию задачи, правильный пароль должен содержать и строчную, и заглавную буквы! Пример неправильного пароля:`ghdfj32` (Неправильный, потому что нет заглавной буквы). Еще неправильный: `DSJKHD23` (Нет строчной буквы). Мой код возвращает `True` (т.к. в данных ранее паролях есть символы, которые указаны в квадратных скобках).

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы регулярное выражение возвращало `True` только в том случае, если в проверяемом тексте есть как минимум по 1-му символу, данному в квадратных скобках (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`)

Comment: Хорошо, что вы исправили опечатку, а то я уже собирался объяснять в ответе, что такое [`[A-z]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте блоки предварительного просмотра:

```
^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
```

Допустимые, но менее эффективные альтернативы:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
```

Пример [работы выражения №1](https://regex101.com/r/Z1PyKG/1) (обратите внимание на то, что в отрицающие символьные классы добавлен шаблон перехода на новую строку, так как в тесте используется многострочный текст, а не несколько отдельных строк) и [пример работы выражений №2](https://regex101.com/r/Y6lsxY/1/).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - положительный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия 0 и более символов, отличных от строчных букв из набора ASCII (см. `[^a-z]*`), а затем одной такой буквы (`[a-z]`) сразу после текущей позиции в строке (выполняет требование "минимум одна строчная буква в строке")
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - минимум одна прописная буква в строке
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` - минимум одна цифра в строке
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}` - шесть и более (см. ограничиващий квантификатор `{6,}`) повторов букв или цифр из набора ASCII
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему выражения `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$` и `^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$` являются менее эффективными?

Comment: @Scourde Потому что поиск любых подстрок с помощью ленивой/жадной точки требует гораздо больше вычислений, чем поиск с помощью символьного класса. Достаточно взглянуть на кол-во шагов, необходиимых для нахождения всех совпадений на regex101.com (разница почти в 2 раза достаточно большая). `.*` "забирает" сразу весь текст, а потом "идёт назад" в поиске совпадений последующих шаблонов, `.*?` "пропускает" последующие шаблоны вперёд, он находит совпадение только если они его не находят. Символьные классы сразу находят только заданные в них символы за один проход.

Comment: Зачем в выражении `^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$` , а именно в блоках  предварительного просмотра вперед нужны повторяющиеся элементы и `*`? Например, `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])`: зачем в этом блоке нужны `[^a-z]`, `*` и `[a-z]`?

Comment: @Scourde Чтобы поиск одной буквы/цифры производился не только в самом начале строки. Блоки предварительного просмотра ищут совпадение своего шаблона сразу перед/после текущей позиции.